# How to combine list numbers into a sum in for-loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of numbers and I am trying to print out each line being added to 0, showing the calculation of adding all the numbers up.

So, goal:

```
sum(0) + list number 1(say 5) = 5
sum(5) + list number 2(12) = 17 
etc.
```

What I currently have:

```
sum=0
for i in range(10):
    print("sum = %d + %d = %2d" %(sum,list[i],sum+list[i]))
```

My problem is the `sum+list[i]` part. Currently it only adds that list number and 0. Im not sure how to carry over the sum so it adds up each line.

Comment: Just add: ‘sum += list[i]’ below the print.

Comment: Recommend changing the `sum` variable name to something else, as its overwriting the builtin function.  And `list` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're super close! You just need to persist your changes to the `sum` variable. One way to do that is:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(10):
    print("sum = %d + %d = %2d" % (sum, list[i], sum+list[i]))
    sum += list[i]
```

Edit: as @S3DEV points out, you should also avoid giving a variable the same name as any of the built-in functions, to avoid overwriting them. I'd suggest something like `total`:

```
total = 0
for i in range(10):
    print("total = %d + %d = %2d" % (total, list[i], total+list[i]))
    total += list[i]
```